# objects in objects with typeHint

Tags: c#, json

I have string

```
{"_t":"P","command":{"_t":"DuelCommand","duelStatus":"Waiting"}}
```

And classes:

```
public class P{
   PingCommand command;
}

public abstract class PingCommand{    
   public virtual void DoCommand(){
   }    
}

public class DuelCommand : PingCommand {
   public virtual void DoCommand(){
   }
}
```

When deserializing it gives me PingCommand instead of DuelCommand, how could I do it right?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net)